# OutOfMemoryError causes commit of JPA transaction

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, deltaspike, deltaspike-jpa

When my system gets "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", it commits the transaction (marked with `org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.Transactional` annotation).

How to avoid this and make a rollback instead? "Regular" exceptions do cause the rollback.

My JPA implementation is EclipseLink 2.6.4 and container is Tomcat 8.5.33 running with Java 8.

Comment: Not sure if it possible maybe there is no heap space to perform anything anymore? So get rid of the OutOfMemoryError at first place.

Comment: commit should never be automatic. How is this transaction setup?

Comment: The method is annotated with `org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.Transactional`, this means transaction is started at method entry and ended (either committed on rolled back) on method exit.

Comment: And how are you sure the OutOfMemoryError is occurring within the transaction itself and not post transaction commit?

Comment: @Chris, the actions in the transaction remain incomplete.

Comment: You have a major server bug then, as an OOM should not cause its transaction handling to commit, and your application should never try to catch it. You are creating a new object (RuntimeException) - even that could get another OOM.

Comment: @Chris, in my case it seems to work, because by the time OutOfMemoryError is caught, JPA seems to have released the stuff that caused the OOM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by catching `OutOfMemoryError` and rethrowing it as `RuntimeException`. This produced proper rollback, garbage collection (because big object graph was released) and service could continue running.